# Overspilling water tank

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> 1. Consider a water tank (Tank 1) containing a volume of water $V_1 (t)$ that is filled at a rate of $q_1 \,\rm{m^3 s^{-1}}$ and drains at a rate $q_2 \,\rm{m^3 s^{-1}}$. Write down the compartmental equation that governs the dynamics of $V_1$.
> 2. Now consider the situation in which Tank 1 is draining into a second tank, Tank 2, containing a volume of water $V_2 (t)$. Suppose further that Tank 2 is also being filled from a second source at a rate $q_3$ , and drains at a rate $q_4$ .
> 3. Suppose $q_1 = A, $q_2 = B$V_1 (t)$, $q_3 = Ct^2$ and $q_4 = A+Dt \,\rm{m^3 s^{-1}}$, where $A,B,C,D$ are positive constants and $t$ is time. Solve for $V_1 (t)$ and $V_2 (t)$ explicitly in terms of $t$, where you may assume $v_{10}$ and $v_{20}$ are known constants.
>
>
>    For large enough $t$, show whether or not Tank 2 will overspill

---

I'm unsure what part (d.ii) means by **"for large enough time show whether tank 2 will overspill"**.

We have derived the volume of both tanks in terms of time, but were not given any information about the amount of water each tank can contain, so how are we meant to show mathematically that the tank has overspilled?

My solution to the other parts is included in the image, I just need a hand figuring out  what the question (d.ii) is asking me to do?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQIRv.jpg): [image: My Solution]

Comment: For example if $V_2(t) \rightarrow +\infty$ as $t \rightarrow +\infty$ then you are sure it will overspill regardless the volume of the tank.

Comment: Ah mate thank you so much for the reply! That makes sense.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks, will do

Comment: Please improve the MathJax.  Once it's good enough, please remove the image and add an image of only the diagram with the water tanks.  Your work can also be MathJax'ed.  Note that search engines find text much more easily than they "read" images.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo        Okay, I will also use this as template to MathJax my future posts